# Consider a function f whose second derivative exists and is continuous in $[0, 1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

Consider a function f whose second derivative exists and is continuous in $[0, 1]$. Suppose that $f (0) = f (1) = 0$
And suppose that there exists $A> 0$ such that $| F''(x) | ≤ A$ for all $x ∈ [0, 1]$. Show that:
$|f'(1/2)|≤ A/4$ and that $|f'(x)|≤ A/2$  for any $x ∈ (0,1)$

I have tried to use Rolle's theorem and the mean value theorem but I have not been able to come up with the answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** for the first.

With  second order Taylor expansion

$f(0)=0=f(\frac 12)-\frac 12f'(\frac 12)+\frac 18f''(c_1)$

$f(1)=0=f(\frac 12)+\frac 12f'(\frac 12)+\frac 18f''(c_2)$

and by substraction

$f'(\frac 12)=\frac 18(f''(c_1)-f''(c_2))$

$\implies |f'(\frac 12)|\leq \frac{2A}{8}$.